# Vagrant default provisioner for command "vagrant provision"

Tags: vagrant, provisioning

Suppose you have two provision blocks defined for your machine

```
config.vm.provision 'A', type: 'file',
  source: 'foo',
  destination: '/opt/foo'
end

config.vm.provision 'B', type: 'file',
  source: 'bar',
  destination: '/opt/bar'
end
```

You can provision your machine with each of them by running

```
vagrant provision --provision-with X
```

where X is either A or B.

How do I select a default provisioner when I only run

```
vagrant provision
```

A use case would be to skip provisioner B and only run provisioner A if **vagrant provision** is executed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related to: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5355